# How to use Sed or Perl to sort given text file based on 2nd column number of string in a descending manner

Tags: perl, sed

How to use Sed or Perl to sort given text file based on 2nd column number of string in a descending manner

Input.txt

```
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy      
123|Z12|Goal|test     
123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl     
123|E1-T23-N12|car|girl     
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12|banana|boy     
123|V1-M12|car|girl     
123|P1-G23-H40-K1|school|boy
```

Output.txt

```
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy   
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12|banana|boy    
123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl    
123|P1-G23-H40-K1|school|boy    
123|E1-T23-N12|car|girl    
123|V1-M12|car|girl     
123|Z12|Goal|test
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet?  Note that Stack Overflow tries to not be a free code writing service.

Comment: I think you mean "descending sort by the number of hyphenated strings in the second column". Is this correct?

Comment: Would `123|Z2|Goal|test` come before or after `123|Z12|Goal|test`? In other words are `Z2` and `Z12` sorted entirely alphabetically or alphabetically on `Z` where they are identical but then numerically on `2` vs `12`? Include that case in your sample input output as so far you have nothing in there to show if the sorting should be partially numerical or not.

Comment: [Tim Biegeleisen] you have the option not to help the starter like me but you have no right to prevent the other from helping the starter . Thanks to -[tshiono] who helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `Schwartzian Transform` in `Perl`, please try the following:

```
perl -e '
    print map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
    map { [$_, length((split(/\|/))[1])] }
    <>;
' input.txt
```

Output:

```
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12|banana|boy
123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl
123|P1-G23-H40-K1|school|boy
123|E1-T23-N12|car|girl
123|V1-M12|car|girl
123|Z12|Goal|test
```

**[How it works]**

To understand the algorithm, it will be convenient to read the script
from the bottom to the top.

The first function:

```
map { [$_, length((split(/\|/))[1])] }
<>;
```

reads the input file, then generates a 2-D list which holds the input line
itself in the 1st column and the length of the 2nd fileld in the 2nd column
something like as:

```
[["123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy\n", 25],
["123|Z12|Goal|test\n", 3],
["123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl\n", 13],
...]]
```

The second function:

```
sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
```

sorts the list by the values in the 2nd columns
in descending order and the result will look like:

```
[["123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy\n", 25],
["123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12|banana|boy\n", 21],
["123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl\n", 18],
...]]
```

The final function:

```
print map { $_->[0] }
```

extracts the 1st columns and prints the result.

The `Schwartzian transform` is a useful and efficient technique (or an idiom)
to sort a list by a certain property of the elements of the list.

Comment: Or: `perl -MSort::Key=ikeysort -e'print ikeysort { -length((split /\|/)[1]) } <>'`

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{ print $1, split($2, a, /-/), $2, $3, $4 }' input.txt |
    sort -t'|' -k 2nr,3 |
    cut -d'|' -f1,3,4,5
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12-J12|banana|boy
123|N1-G23-H40-K1-A11-C12|banana|boy
123|F1-B23-G39-M22-Z12|some|girl
123|P1-G23-H40-K1|school|boy
123|E1-T23-N12|car|girl
123|V1-M12|car|girl
123|Z12|Goal|test
```

The `awk` bit adds a new second column that is the number of `-`-separated words in the original second column. `sort` then sorts that output by first sorting that new second column in reverse numeric order, and for each line where that number is the same, sorts the third column (original second) in ascending lexicographic order. Finally, `cut` removes that extra column.